# Generating graph-tool graph from Pandas DataFrame or CSV

Tags: python, pandas, graph, graph-tool

I've started using `graph-tool`, hoping it would be a python library that will allow me to analyze large graphs (`~8M` vertices, `~22M` edges, in a Pandas DataFrame / CSV). 'source' and 'target' columns are user ids for a certain digital service.

I started out with a toy example, following the method [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459597/graph-tool-reading-edge-lists-from-pandas-dataframe).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'source':range(11,15), 'target':range(12,16)})

g = Graph(directed=True)

g.add_edge_list(df.values)
```

you can see in my dummy example, there are only 5 distinct vertices `(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)`. However, when I generate the graph, 16 vertices are created, seemingly filling the gap between 0 and the max node value.

```
g.get_vertices()

returns:

    array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], dtype=uint64)
```

I assume that graph-tool 'reads' the values of the df as indices, not as the actual vertices' names. This follows from the [docs](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#creating-and-manipulating-graphs):

> Each vertex in a graph has an unique index, which is always between
>   :math:0 and :math:N-1, where :math:N is the number of vertices.

How do I create a graph without these redundant vertices (which, if I import my data, could be in the millions), and how can I get to work with my user ids not being regarded as indices? 
I've been rummaging through the available methods / documentation and couldn't figure it out, for the mass import from df case.

*What else I tried:*

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)#, header=False)    
g2 = graph_tool.load_graph_from_csv('test.csv', skip_first=True)
```

This does seem to create a graph with only 5 vertices, but 'loses' their names (user ids).

```
g2.get_vertices()
```

returns

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=uint64)
```

Instead of `[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]`.

Appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

I am using `python 2.7` on `Jupyter/Anaconda`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is enabled by the `hashed` parameter of the `add_edge_list()` method:

```
vmap = g.add_edge_list(df.values, hashed=True)
```

where `vmap` is a property map with the vertex "names".

From the docstring:

> Optionally, if `hashed == True`, the vertex values in the edge list
>       are not assumed to correspond to vertex indices directly. In this case
>       they will be mapped to vertex indices according to the order in which
>       they are encountered, and a vertex property map with the vertex values
>       is returned. If `string_vals == True`, the algorithm assumes that the
>       vertex values are strings. Otherwise, they will be assumed to be numeric
>       if `edge_list` is a :class:`~numpy.ndarray`, or arbitrary python
>       objects if it is not.

Note that to guarantee efficient data structures, in graph-tool vertices are *always* contiguous integers, so they will always be numbered from 0 to N-1. If you want to give them different "names", you have to use property maps, as described in the documentation.

Comment: How would you proceed after that? I tried `v_name = g.add_edge_list(edges.values, string_vals=True, hashed=True, eprops=e_weight)` But I got `Unpickling Error`. edges is a `DataFrame` `e_weight` is initiated as a edge property and v_name are nodes names properly initiated as vertex properties as strings. Thanks,

Comment: Yes, it does not look like a complete answer. Ends with '.. as described in the documentation, which is not great, IMO.